# Bitbucket - enviar novos arquivos a um repositório vazio

Tags: bitbucket, mercurial

Criei um novo repositório Mercurial no bitbucket chamado `MEUNOVOREP`.

Agora eu tenho um diretório no meu `c:\novoprojeto` que tem uma série de arquivos que eu quero enviar para este repositório.

Minha dúvida:
Como associar este meu diretório `c:\novoprojeto` ao meu Repositório `MEUNOVOREP`, para que depois eu selecione os arquivos que vou enviar e arquivos que vou ignorar?

Comment: Na página do seu repositório no bitbucket explica como realizar essa associação. Use o comando `hg push <<REPOSITORIO>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para inicializar um repositório:

```
hg init c:\novoprojeto
```

Para enviar o repositório para o Bitbucket:

```
cd novoprojeto
hg push https://bitbucket.org/marquinhos/meunovorep
```